# Syntax of If Statement Regarding XML in Silverlight WP7 App

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

everyone!  I couldn't find a tutorial explaining the right way to code this.  I think it will be clear from the title and the code what I'm trying to do.  The two errors I'm receiving is that my if statement is in the wrong place, and that the variable 'Arrow' is assigned but never used.  I know this comes down to simple syntax, so I thank everyone for their time.

```
void DATABASEinfo_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        XElement xmlitem = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

        var list = new List<DATABASEinfoViewModel>();            


        foreach (XElement item in xmlitem.Element("channel").Elements("item"))
        {
            var title = item.Element("title");
            var titlevalue = (title == null) ? null : title.Value;
            var description = item.Element("description");
            var descriptionvalue = (description == null) ? null : description.Value;                
            var arrow = (xmlitem.Element("title").Value.Contains("DATABASE Up"))
                ? "up" : null;


            list.Add(new DATABASEinfoViewModel
            {
                Title = titlevalue,
                Description = descriptionvalue,
                Arrow = arrow,                   
            });
        }                       

        DATABASEinfoList.ItemsSource = list;           
    }          

    public class DATABASEinfoViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Arrow { get; set; }
```

Oddly, if I change:

```
var arrow = (xmlitem.Element("title").Value.Contains("DATABASE Up"))
```

To:

```
var arrow = (xmlitem.Element("channel").Value.Contains("DATABASE Up"))
```

It displays "up" for ALL entries.  Here is an example of the XML file:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title> DATABASE Status</title>
<description>DATABASE status updates</description>      

<item>
<title>First status is DATABASE Up</title>
<description>First Content</description>
</item>

<item>
<title>Second status is DATABASE Up</title>
<description>Second Content</description>
</item>

</channel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
var arrow = (xmlitem.Element("title").Value.Contains("DATABASE Up"))
```

should actually be

```
var arrow = (item.Element("title").Value.Contains("DATABASE Up"))
```

You should be querying **item**, not **xmlitem**.

As mentioned in other answers, you should also be checking that elements exist before accessing their values.

Answer (score 0):

if doesn't return a result that you can assign to var arrow.

Where you trying to do something like this?

```
    string arrow = "";
    if (xmlitem.Element("description").Value.Contains("DATABASE Up"))
    {
        arrow = ("up");                
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, the syntax was correct.  However, it opened up a new can of worms.  The debugger highlights the "if (xmlitem.Element("description").Value.Contains("DATABASE Up")" line and gives me a "NullReferenceException was unhandled" error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do.  If the `description` contains "DATABASE Up" you want the value of `arrow` to be "up" otherwise what?  null?

```
string arrow = null;

if (xmlitem.Element("description").Value.Contains("DATABASE Up")) 
{ 
    arrow = ("up");                 
}
```

or

```
var arrow = (xmlitem.Element("description").Value.Contains("DATABASE Up"))
            ? "up" : null;
```

**EDIT**

And why are you setting `DATABASEinfoList.ItemsSource = list` both inside the foreach loop and again outside?  The one inside should probably go away.

Also, there's an inherent problem, shown by your comment in Mick's answer..  These calls:

```
 item.Element("[elementName]").Value
```

assume that the element exists.  If it doesn't you'll call the `Value` Property getter on a null, throwing a NullReferenceException.  If there's a chance that the element would be null, then you need to check for that before calling Value:

```
 var element = item.Element("[elementName]");
 var value = (element == null) ? null : element.Value;
```

Comment: I updated my code to the best of my knowledge using your suggestions, but I still get a NullReferenceException.  The description fields in the XML file do not ONLY contain the words "DATABASE Up", but something like "The status is DATABASE Up".  Would that effect anything negatively?